# Detect loops/intersections in matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

At some point in my work, I came up with [that kind](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5I5iDYahBuNUGxBMi1uM2lFYzg/view?usp=sharing) of scatter plot.

I would like for my script to be able to detect the fact that it "loops" and to give me the point (or an approximation thereof) where it does so : for instance, in this case it would be about [0.2,0.1].

I tried to play around with some representative quantities of my points, like norm and/or argument, like in the following piece of code.

```
import numpy as np

x,y = np.genfromtxt('points.dat',unpack=True)
norm = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
arg = np.arctan2(y,x)

left,right = np.meshgrid(norm,norm)
norm_diff = np.fabs(left - right)
mask = norm_diff == 0.
norm_diff_ma = np.ma.masked_array(norm_diff,mask)

left,right = np.meshgrid(arg,arg)
arg_diff = np.fabs(left - right)
mask = arg_diff == 0.
arg_diff_ma = np.ma.masked_array(arg_diff,mask)

list_of_indices = np.ma.where((norm_diff_ma<1.0e-04)*(arg_diff_ma<1.0e-04))
```

But, it does not work as intended : might be because the dataset contains too many points and the distance between two aligned points is anyhow of the same order of magnitude as the distance between the points in the "loop cluster" ...

I was thinking about detecting clusters, or maybe even detecting lines in the scatter plot and then see if there are any intersections between any two lines, but I am afraid my skills in image processing only go so far.

Is there any algorithm, any trick that any of you can think about would work here ?

A representative data sample can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5I5iDYahBuNR2hNUlJkUVE2RDA/view?usp=sharing).

**Edit 08/13/2015 16h18** : after the short discussion with @DrBwts I took a closer look at the data I obtained after a pyplot.contour() call. Using the following routine to extract all the vertices :

```
def contour_points(contour, steps=1):
try:
    loc_arr = np.row_stack([path.interpolated(steps).vertices for linecol in contour.collections for path in linecol.get_paths()])
except ValueError:
    loc_arr = np.empty((0,2))
finally:
    return loc_arr
y,x = contour_points(CS,steps=1).T
```

it turns out the points of coordinates (x,y) **are** ordered, in the sense where a call to pyplot.plot() connects the dots correctly.

Comment: Are the data points collected sequentially? By that I mean is there an order to the data points? If so, I think I would do something with the changes in direction between points.

Comment: @DrBwts : Thank you for your input. There is no order to the data points sadly - or none I know of. To get them, I actually stack all the vertices of all paths contained in a pyplot.contour(x,y,mtx,0.0) collection.

Comment: If you dont mind me asking, what is the source of the data?

Comment: @DrBwts : No, no problem ! I have a matrix **A** which depends on four parameters **ar**, **ai**, **b** and **r**. For each quadruplet I store the eigenvalue of **A** which has the greatest imaginary part - say **x**. I can do plenty with that 5-dimensional dataset, but I am interested in the following : for **b** and **r** fixed, I want to know if any isoline of **x** in the (**ar**,**ai**) plane has a pinch point (i.e it crosses itself). The values of **ar**, **ai** and **x** at those potential pinch points are some representation of the stability of the system described by **A**.

Comment: and the plots are of **x** on the **(ar, ai)** plane I take it?

Comment: @DrBwts : yes, indeed. The figure attached to my question post is the isoline **x = 0** extracted at some **b** and **r**, with the abscissa being **ar** and the ordinate **ai**.

Comment: This actually has more to do with math and geometry than programming.  What you're looking for is a way to detect line intersections - if a single polyline crosses itself it inherently must form a loop.  There are some good basic geometry algorithms and explanations [here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a05-_intersect-1.html) on line segment intersections.

Comment: @Ajean : I get your point, but it really is a programming question. Given a parametric application from R to R, I would know how to identify pinch points using curvilinear coordinates and the toolbox that comes with it. Now, what I am trying to figure out is how to find pinch points given a discrete set of points in 2d space that may, or may not, respect a coherent curvilinear coordinate system. In other words, how can we assess if a set of scattered points forms some kind of "cross", and, in the affirmative, where the crossing point is.